# SQL - Insert new record into table based on rows chosen from previous query

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

I'm hoping someone can help me out or point me in the right direction if I'm approaching this incorrectly altogether.

My intention is to select eligible users from a database based on a specific criteria. Of those that are returned and displayed on the page, the admin user should be able to select from those users and add them to another table in the database, this time with a fee attached.

I'm at the point where the users are correctly displayed and I've attached the fee to the value of the checkbox but I can't seem to figure out how to re-enter the users back into the new table.

I hope samples of my code below are clear enough to help clarify where I'm going with this.

I realize this may not be the most efficient approach. Any suggestions or advice are gladly welcome.

Thanks!

PHP to select eligible users

```
$sql = $db->prepare("       
        SELECT *
        FROM users                                              
        WHERE user_registration = 1
        ");
$sql ->execute();
$users = $sql ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

HTML & PHP to display eligible users with checkbox

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th class="checked">Select</th>                            
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Birth Date</th>
        <th>Fee</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <?php foreach($users as $entry): ?>

        <tr>
            <td class="checked">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="<?php echo $entry->fee; ?>"/> 
            </td>
            <td class="first-name"><?php echo $entry->first_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->last_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->birthdate; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->fee; ?></td>                                     
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </tbody>
</table> 


<div id="total" name="total">$0
</div>
```

JS to calculate fee for each user

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.option').click(function(){

        var total = 0;

        $('.option:checked').each(function(){

            total += parseInt($(this).val());

        });

        $('#total').html('$' + total);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="<?php echo $entry->fee; ?>"/>
```

do

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="<?php echo $entry->id; ?>"/>
```

Then when a checkbox is checked and form is submitted You have the IDs of that users and You can do a simple

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT FROM table1 WHERE table1.id IN (/* Your comma separated IDs here*/)
```